# Как подключить свой класс в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Я новичок в Yii2. Мне написал класс, который из даты вида "DD-MM-YY H:M:S" делает красивую дату.
Вопрос:

1. В какую папку положить мой класс?
2. Какое указать пространство имен?
3. Как правильно подключить его?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сделать аналогию yii1, вроде компонента, то так и кладите в components. Пространство имен соответственно app\components. Подключать как любой другой класс, в нужном вам классе `use app\components\ClassName` и используйте. Но вообще лично я бы сделал для подобных вещей отдельный контроллер и просто для решения этой задачи создал бы в нем метод

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно именно форматирование даты, то воспользуйтесь formatter

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('now', 'php:Y-m-d'); // 2014-10-06
```

Подробнее https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-ru/output-formatting/

Если же вы просто пытаетесь разобраться в структуре фреймворка, то ответ зависит от шаблона:
Если вы используете шаблон basic, то создавайте папку components, подключение:

```
 use app\components\ComponentName.
```

Если вы используете шаблон advanced, то создавайте папку common/components, подключение:

```
 use common\components\ComponentName.
```